# Install SFML binding to Ada

Tags: ubuntu, installation, sfml, ada, graphical-interaction

My OS is Ubuntu.  I downloaded the SFML binding to Ada.

However, on this one the way of proceed  according to the OS is not described!

Stage by stage, here is what I have done:

1) `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev`

2) download the binding here: https://github.com/danva994/ASFML-1.6

As you can see , there is no detailed method of installation anywhere.

Obviously, when i compile the example in their "window" directory, I got an error:

```
dead-code@Machine:~/Bureau/SFML/ASFML-1.6-master/tests/window$ gnatmake main.adb -I<ASFML-1.6/include> -largs -L<ASFML-1.6/lib> -l<csfml-libs> -l<sfml-libs> -lstdc++
bash: ASFML-1.6/include: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
dead-code@Machine:~/Bureau/SFML/ASFML-1.6-master/tests/window$
```

It says: "bash: ASFML-1.6/include: no such file or directory"

Comment: Did you try to follow the instructions in `README.txt`?

Comment: Remove the `<` & `>`, they are used to redirect input/output in shells.

Comment: Jacob = Of fource i had read the redme , the problem is that there is praticly nothing .

Comment: hiura = it's better but still doesn't work , but  a needed lib  had disapear from the package list : http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/lib32stdc++6  . /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcsfml-libs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-libs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Comment: You need to replace `-l<csfml-libs>` and `-l<sfml-libs>` by specific value such as `-lsfml-graphics`, etc. You need to check `SFML` official documentation to know which library you must link. `<ASFML-1.6/include>` must be replace by the real directory.